# Improve perfomance of synchronized 2D array

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm writing a multi-player game, and I need some solution which will represent the play field. I implemented for demo Synchronized2DArray class, but I think this is not the best way. Synchronized block locks whole array, while I need to lock only one cell. Is it possible to lock only one cell or may be there are other ways to improve perfomance?

```
class Synchronized2DArray {
    private int[][] array;

    public Synchronized2DArray(int size) {            
        array = new int[size][size];
    }

    public void setValue(int x, int y, int value) {
        synchronized (array) {
            array[x][y] = value;
        }
    }

    public int getValue(int x, int y) {
        synchronized (array) {
            return array[x][y];
        }
    }

.................       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your *real* problems are on *different* levels:

1. Your abstractions are "lousy". You see, in good OO design you create classes to *abstract*; in order to create a reasonable, **helpful** model of the things you are dealing with. An array of int values ... is providing only a tiny bit of abstraction.
2. Then there is also a *misconception* on how locking works. You are **not** "locking" the whole array. Instead, you wrote code that makes sure that calls to `getValue()` and `setValue()` are *serialized*. The above code makes it impossible that one thread sets a value while another thread is reading that value. There is a subtle difference there.

So, my (pretty generic) answer would be: you should step back and spent some time thinking on

1. creating an object model that helps you implementing your ideas in a true, OO way.
2. what kind of parallel activities will be possible, and for which one you want to optimize.

For example, you could change your current locking approach to use a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) instead; allowing unlimited reader access; but making sure that writing will not happen in parallel.

Comment: "The above code makes it impossible that one thread sets a value while another thread is reading that value."
Thanks, I didn't thought about that

Comment: Yes. I just want to make sure that you understand that using synchronized(array) doesnt magically prevent updates on that array. You are not turning some "magic switch" that would prevent *other* methods to update the array object in parallel!

Comment: Read about locks -  ReentrantReadWriteLock class resolves my problem.

And about OO design and abstractions - I think in my case there is no need to make abstract parent to this class. There will be only one implementation.  This synchronized array is an inner class of class which represents field and its logic.

Answer (score 1):

GhostCat has a point, but I can see performance as a possible reason for using arrays here. You probably want to keep a play field in an array and you want to use an array of some primitive type here to avoid the overhead of large numbers of objects. This is not easily abstracted away in Java, though the set and get methods might map the ints to something more meaningful.

More specifically to your question:
You could synchronize on a single row or column of your array like this:

```
synchronized (array[x]) { ... }
```

You cannot easily synchronize on just one cell as synchronization in Java only works on objects but not on primitive datatypes like int.
If you used objects as cell elements (e.g. Integer instead of int), you could synchronize on a single cell but the memory and performance overhead is probably too big to make this a good idea.

Comment: Valid point, too. But I have the vague feeling that he is not using an array of int for that reason ...